# Loading OBJ model data using regexes?

Tags: c++, regex, opengl, glm-math, wavefront

I'm trying to write a class for loading a **.obj* model, but I ran into a problem.

I'm fetching vertex data and vertex indexes from a **.obj* file. For this I use regular expressions.

With prefix `v`:

```
Regex: v ([-+]?([0]\.[0-9]*|[1-9]*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)) ([-+]? ([0]\.[0-9]*|[1-9]*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)) ([-+]?([0]\.[0- 9]*|[1-9]*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*))
```

With prefix `f`:

```
Regex: f ([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)\/.*\/.* ([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)\ /.*\/.* ([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)\/.*\/.*
```

All values are added to vectors:

```
std::vector<glm::fvec3> vertices_postion;
std::vector<GLint> vertices_postion_indicies;
```

Next, the data is sent to OpenGL:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_postion.size() * sizeof(glm::fvec3), &vertices_postion[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_postion_indicies.size() * sizeof(GLint), &vertices_postion_indicies[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

In terms of rendering:

```
glUseProgram(shader->getProgram());
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertices_postion_indicies.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
```

The cube model was made in Autodesk Inventor and then exported to .OBJ format.

However, the rendering does not look correct, I think there are problems with the vertex rendering indexes.

Vertices:

```
v1: -5 v2: 0  v3: -5
v1: -5 v2: 0  v3: 5
v1: -5 v2: 10 v3: 5
v1: -5 v2: 10 v3: -5
v1: 5  v2: 0  v3: -5
v1: 5  v2: 10 v3: -5
v1: 5  v2: 0  v3: 5
v1: 5  v2: 10 v3: 5
```

Vertex indices:

```
1,2,4,4,2,3,5,1,6,6,1,4,7,5,8,8,5,6,2,7,3,3,7,8,2,1,7,7,1,5,8,6,3,3,6,4
```

Picture:

[image: Incorrect cube]

Comment: Obj indicies are 1-based, OpenGL indicies are 0-based.

Comment: OBJ indices can also be negative.

Comment: @genpfault, How then is it to be interpreted?

Comment: "In addition to counting vertices down from the top of the first list in the file, you can also count vertices back up the list from an element's position in the file.  When you count up the list from an element, the reference numbers are negative. A reference number of -1 indicates the vertex immediately above the element.  A reference number of -2 indicates two references above and so on." [Ref](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec)